# Remove from Parent DIV container

Tags: javascript, html

i have got this :

```
    <div id="video_pattern">
      <div id="des"position:relative;></div>
      <div id="mes"position:relative;></div>
    </div>
```

i want to remove the

```
>  <div id="video_pattern">
```

but the

```
  <div id="des"position:relative;></div>
          <div id="mes"position:relative;></div>
```

should stay, is this possible?

Comment: On a side note you need to make your HTML validate. <div id="des"position:relative;></div> Should be <div id="des" style="position:relative;"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle your exact situation you can use this code:

```
  var ToRemoveElement = document.getElementById("video_pattern");

  ToRemoveElement.parentNode.appendChild(document.getElementById("des"));
  ToRemoveElement.parentNode.appendChild(document.getElementById("mes"));

  ToRemoveElement.remove();
```

This is the way to go if you only want these specific elements removed from the video_pattern div. If you want a more generic solution to remove all child elements then use the following:

```
  var ToRemoveElement = document.getElementById("video_pattern");

  var children = ToRemoveElement.children;
  while (children.length > 0) {
    ToRemoveElement.parentNode.appendChild(children[0]);
  }    
  ToRemoveElement.remove();
```

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/azBth/)

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can do like this

```
var inner = $("#video_pattern").contents();
$("#video_pattern").replaceWith(inner);
```